# Batch file that will print all files (.pdf's and .docs) in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, printing, dos

Running Win7, I need a batch file that will print all .doc and .pdf files in a particular directory. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need [printJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/printJS.bat) in the same directory:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\directory_with_documents"
for %%a in (*.pdf *.doc) do (
   call printjs.bat "%%~fa"
)
```

and to change the directory at the beginning.
Have on mind that printJS uses invokeverb function which may fail if language on the system is different than English.

Comment: How can we change it to only print first 2 pages?